# Глобальная переменная Perl

Tags: perl

Здравствуйте! Подскажите как объявить переменную глобальной и получить к ней доступ в другом модуле?
В обработчике  ticket.pl я формирую массив,а в другом обработчике  all_zakaz.pl мне нужно получить к ней доступ.

```
our @arr;  //  не помогает..
```

Comment: Не понял, как взаимосвязаны обработчики? Один `require`-ит другой, или это отдельные скрипты?

Comment: отдельные, первый обработчики извлекает параметры из формы через CGI, методом  param,  помещает в массив все, генерирует страницу со сылкой просмтреть все заказы - ссылка ведет на обработчик2 котрый сначала должен записать в БД массив из первого обработчика и потом вывести на странницу

Comment: Ну, я бы тогда в первом сразу сохранял в БД, а потом уже возвращал страницу со ссылкой. В идеале - код, который сохраняет/достаёт заказы из БД (и _ничего_ кроме не делает) - вынес в отдельный pm, который бы и use-ал из обоих скриптов.

Answer (score 2):

В Perl нет такого понятия как глобальная переменная - в нём каждая переменная принадлежит пакету, в котором она объявлена (или даже блоку, если это лексическая переменная). Если переменная объявлена при помощи `my`, к ней нельзя обращаться из других пакетов, если при помощи `our` - можно обращаться по полному имени (с указанием пакета). То есть в вашем случае это будет:

```
package MyModule;

our @numbers = 1 .. 3;

1;

# В другом файле:
use MyModule;
print join ', ', @MyModule::numbers;
```

Также переменные и функции можно экспортировать из других пакетов в текущий при помощи модуля Exporter (или других), чтобы обращаться к ним по короткому имени без указания пакета:

```
package MyModule;
use Exporter;
use base 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(@numbers);

our @numbers = 4 .. 6;

1;

# В другом файле:
use MyModule qw(@numbers);

print join ', ', @numbers;
```

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите как сделано: [How to share/export a global variable between two different perl scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543934/how-to-share-export-a-global-variable-between-two-different-perl-scripts)

Comment: проблема в том, что когда я формирую массив в первом обработчике, я подключаю 
   

    use CGI;


   и когда одновременно с ним включаю 


    use strict;
    use Fcntl;
    use SDBM_File;


    все бьется..( они что несовместимы?

Answer (score 0):

Может быть старый и простой метод:

```
package A;
our $array = [qw/11 22 33/];

package B;
use A;

say $A::array->[0];#output: 11
```

Comment: пока не могу проверить ваш способ,  надеюсь получится..спасибо!

Comment: а нужно Exporter  подключать?


    package имя_модуля; # Такое же как и имя этого файла без расширения '.pm'
 require Exporter; # Обязательная строка для экспорта имен
 @ISA = qw(Exporter); # -//-
 @EXPORT = qw(func1 func2) # Перечисляем имена функций. Внимание ! нет запятой!
 @EXPORT_OK = qw( $переменная @массив ); # Указать публичные переменные, массивы
                                и т.д. если необходимо